# simple SELECT COUNT(*) extremely slow on Google CloudSQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I have a query to perform in a table in MySQL.
However, Google Cloud SQL is very slow to return the results :

```
SELECT count(*) from navegacao
```

==>  Takes 4 minutes to count 40,000,000 rows

**Isn't this an extremely long time for this? How can I improve computation time by modifying my request or the structure of my table?**

This time doesn't change when I increase the performance of the MySQL database, even with bigger machines like "Standard 16 CPU machine type with 16 virtual CPUs and 60 GB of memory."

A few requests that seem on interest on related topics :

SHOW INDEX FROM navegacao returns me :

```
TABLE_NAME                                          NON_UNIQUE  INDEX_NAME                                          SEQ_IN_INDEX  COLUMN_NAME                                         COLLATION  CARDINALITY            SUB_PART  PACKED      NULL  INDEX_TYPE        COMMENT           INDEX_COMMENT                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
navegacao                                           0           PRIMARY                                             1             navegacaobk                                         A          35037900               <null>    <null>            BTREE                                                                                   
navegacao                                           1           memberid                                            1             memberid                                            A          7007580                <null>    <null>      YES   BTREE                                                                                   
navegacao                                           1           ofertaid                                            1             ofertaid                                            A          547467                 <null>    <null>      YES   BTREE                                                                                   
navegacao                                           1           productid                                           1             productid                                           A          200216                 <null>    <null>      YES   BTREE
```

and the schema of the table is the following :

```
1   campaign    VARCHAR 255
2   datacalendario  DATE    10
3   medium  VARCHAR 255
4   memberid    VARCHAR 255
5   navegacaobk VARCHAR 255
6   productlistposition VARCHAR 255
7   productlistname VARCHAR 255
8   skunavigation   VARCHAR 255
9   ofertaid    VARCHAR 255
10  productid   VARCHAR 255
11  source  VARCHAR 255
12  productaddstocart   DECIMAL 12
13  productcheckouts    DECIMAL 12
14  productdetailview   DECIMAL 12
15  productlistview DECIMAL 12
16  productuniquepurchases  DECIMAL 12
17  cicheckin   DECIMAL 12
18  cicheckout  DECIMAL 12
19  cireservar  DECIMAL 12
20  productlistclics    DECIMAL 12
21  totalamountcireservar   DECIMAL 12
22  productrevenue  DECIMAL 12
```

The explain select count(*) from navegacao request :

```
id   select_type          table                                               type        possible_keys                                       key                                                 key_len                                             ref                                                 rows        Extra                                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    SIMPLE               navegacao                                           index       <null>                                              memberid                                            768                                                 <null>                                              35037900    Using index
```

in the end my final request is supposed to be something like

```
select memberid,max(datacalendario) as lastvisdate  from  navegacao where productid in (591,64,8985,774,9) and datacalendario > curdate()-100 group by memberid
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'increase the performance of MySQL database'?

Comment: @LONG : CloudSQL uses several machine types, specified here : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types  I tried to increase temporarily the RAM and number of cores but to no avail.

Comment: I see, I am not very sure about how VM works here, but if you could check the `server properties` by right click server instance, maybe you could see if enough memory allocated for that server, again, not very sure how does this work in your case

Comment: assume if you are working under the same server condition, my attempt answer may give you a brief idea for query optimaztion

Answer (score 2):

For the `Count(*)`, you could hardly optimize the query by using this command, it is just counting every rows from the table without using any index, basically it is doing the table scan. You mentioned that you have switched using a system with better performance, did you change the connection when running the same query?

For the last step, you have already had non-clustered index for `productid`, which will grant you better performance when the query utilizing that column to get the result. Since you have another condition specified for `datacalendario`, you could either create another non-clustered index for that column or create a composite index for `productid` and `datacalendario` regarding that particular query performance improvement.